# Cannot pass parameter to be property name for an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters, properties

```
const persons = {
    name: 'David',
    age: 40
};

const myFunction = (x) => {
    console.log(persons.x)
};

myFunction('name');
```

If I pass myFunction('name'), I expect it to print 'David'.

If I pass myFunction('age'), I expect it to print 40.

But now it prints undefined. Anyone has any solutions ?

Answer (score -1):

```
const persons = {
    name: 'David',
    age: 40
};

const myFunction = (x) => {
    console.log(persons[x])
};

myFunction('name');
```

If you want to use a variable, you have to use the square bracket notation (`object[property_name]`) instead of the dot notation (`object.property_name`).